# Adding AJAX/jQuery to simple PHP Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I understand how to make a simple form with just PHP, but am now trying to understand how to add AJAX/jQuery to this process.

Unfortunately I do not know enough about AJAX/jQuery to see what I'm doing wrong.

I've been following a tutorial that sets up an AJAX form however it doesn't actually write to the MYSQL db. I've added in database and PDO to the code but when I submit, I'm not getting errors and it's not submitting to the database.

Can someone point out what I am missing?

**index.html**

```
<h1>Processing an AJAX Form</h1>

    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
        <!-- Name -->
        <div id="name-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <!-- Errors -->
        </div>

        <!-- Class -->
        <div id="class-group">
            <label for="class">Class</label>
            <input type="text" name="class" placeholder="Class">
            <!-- Errors -->
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Process form
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // Remove the error class
    $('.help-block').remove(); // Remove the error text

    // Get form data
    var formData = {
        'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'class': $('input[name=class]').val()
    };

    // Process form
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: formData, // Data object
        dataType: 'json', // Type of data expected back from server
        encode: true
    })

        // Using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // Log data to the console
            console.log(data);

            // Handle errors and validation messages
            if (!data.success) {

                // Handle errors for name
                if (data.errors.name) {
                    $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); // Add the error class to show red input
                    $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>'); // Add the actual error message under our input
                }

                if (data.errors.class) {
                    $('#class-group').addClass('has-error'); // Add the error class to show red input
                    $('#class-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.class + '</div>'); // Add the actual error message under our input
                }
            } else {
                // Show success message
                $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
                // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page
                //alert('success'); // for now we'll just alert the user
            }
        })

        .fail(function(data) {

            console.log(data);
        });

    // Stop form from submitting the normal method and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';

$errors = []; // Array to hold validation errors
$data   = []; // Array to pass back data

$name  = $_POST['name'];
$class = $_POST['class'];

// Validate the variables
// If variables do not exist, add an error to $errors array
if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required';
}

if (empty($class)) {
    $errors['class'] = 'Class is required';
}

// Return a response
// If there are any errors in errors array, return a success boolean of false
if (!empty($errors)) {
    // If there are errors in errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
    // If there are no errors process form, then return message

    // Form processing here
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO class(name, class_id) values(?, ?)";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        $name,
        $class
    ));
    Database::disconnect();

    // Show a message of success and provide a true success variable
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

// Return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work when you add your POST variables - have you ensured that the script is called?  You can test this in chrome by opening the developer console, going to the network tab and then submitting your form - if all is well you should see a `process.php` script appended to the panel, inspect the headers here and see if your data was sent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$name` and `$class` was used but not assigned, assign values to them.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
```

Comment: Thanks added this and updated question, but no luck still doesn't input into MYSQL and no error.

Comment: Re-checked the code, there were some fields I changed in the .js that were not correct. But using your suggestion worked.